# How to integrate Authorize.net into nest js for credit card payment facility?

Tags: nest, authorize.net

How to integrate Authorize.net into nest js for credit card payment facility?

async chargeCreditCard(amount: number, cardDetails: any): Promise {
var merchantAuthenticationType = new AuthorizeNet.APIContracts.MerchantAuthenticationType();
merchantAuthenticationType.setName('5KP3u9');
merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey('346HZ32z3hTG2');

```
    var creditCard = new AuthorizeNet.APIContracts.CreditCardType();
    creditCard.setCardNumber('4242424242424242');
    creditCard.setExpirationDate('0826'); // Format: "YYYY-MM"
    creditCard.setCardCode('899');

    var paymentType = new AuthorizeNet.APIContracts.PaymentType();
    paymentType.setCreditCard(creditCard);

    var transactionRequestType = new AuthorizeNet.APIContracts.TransactionRequestType();
    transactionRequestType.setTransactionType(AuthorizeNet.APIContracts.TransactionTypeEnum.AUTHCAPTURETRANSACTION);
    transactionRequestType.setPayment(paymentType);
    transactionRequestType.setAmount(amount);

    var createRequest = new AuthorizeNet.APIContracts.CreateTransactionRequest();
    createRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);
    createRequest.setTransactionRequest(transactionRequestType);

    var ctrl = new AuthorizeNet.APIControllers.CreateTransactionController(createRequest.getJSON());


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ctrl.execute(function(){
        var apiResponse = ctrl.getResponse();

        var response = new AuthorizeNet.APIContracts.CreateTransactionResponse(apiResponse);

        // Handle the response as per your requirement
        if (response != null) {
          if (response.getMessages().getResultCode() === AuthorizeNet.APIContracts.MessageTypeEnum.OK) {
            resolve(response.getTransactionResponse().getTransId());
          } else {
            reject(response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText());
          }
        } else {
          reject("Null Response.");
        }
      });
    });
  }
```